# iOS external link to physical store policy

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store, appstore-approval, policy

Let's say if i have a story book app on the app store, can i put a "buy physical book" button in the app, which link to my website that sell the physical book?

I only found this on apple iOS policy saying that you can't do it with digital book.

11.3 : Apps that link to external mechanisms for purchases or subscriptions to be used in the App, such as a "buy" button that goes to a web site to purchase a digital book, will be rejected

Any help or link is good, Thanks!!

Comment: Your book is physical right? I would say: give it a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple policies refers to selling of digital goods. In your case you are selling physical books through your website which also have reference on your app. I don't think apple will be concerned about this. Instead of redirecting user directly to payment screen in website, show them the product detail screen which have all the information about the book.

> 3.1.5 Physical Goods and Services Outside of the App: If your app enables people to purchase goods or services that will be consumed outside of the app, you must use purchase methods other than IAP to collect those payments, such as Apple Pay or traditional credit card entry. Apps may facilitate transmission of approved virtual currencies (e.g. Bitcoin, DogeCoin) provided that they do so in compliance with all state and federal laws for the territories in which the app functions.

Comment: exactly what i'm looking for, thanks for your answer =)